# How to use SharePoint theme in TSX file (but not a css class)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Can anyone let me know the design pattern to use a SharePoint styling colour like themePrimary in a .tsx file (but not a css class).

Can only find references on how to use these variables in .scss or as css classes in a .tsx file via the Microsoft docs.

I would like to use it on this calendar component:

```
  <FullCalendar
    eventColor={themePrimary} //#000000
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the same methodology as outlined in the [Supporting section backgrounds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/supporting-section-backgrounds) article.

Here's the summary:

- Set `supportsThemeVariants` to true in your manifest
- Add `import { ThemeProvider, ThemeChangedEventArgs, IReadonlyTheme } from '@microsoft/sp-component-base';` to your webpart
- Setup a `ThemeProvider` using `this.context.serviceScope.consume(ThemeProvider.serviceKey);`
- Get access to the theme using `this._themeProvider.tryGetTheme();`
- Use the theme doing something like this:

```
  <FullCalendar
    eventColor={themeVariant.palette.themePrimary}
  />
```

Alternatively, a less safe way is to do something like this:

```
let primaryThemeColor = window["__themeState__"].theme.themePrimary;
```